# Null Pointer Exception for JdbcTemplate with SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm pretty new to Java, but I wanted to try to build a simple project with SpringMVC. It's just a simple CRUD app that should allow people to post notes.

When attempting to submit the form or query for notes, I get a null pointer exception when I attempt to call methods on JdbcTemplate. Here is the code for my application class:

```
package mvc;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMvcApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void run(String... string) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating tables");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("drop table notes if exists");
        jdbcTemplate.execute(("create table notes(" +
                "id serial, content varchar(255), author varchar(255))"));
    }

    public static SpringMvcApplication instance = new SpringMvcApplication();
    public static SpringMvcApplication getInstance() { return instance; }

}
```

Here is my NoteController.java:

```
package mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class NoteController {
    @RequestMapping("/notes")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/notes/new")
    public String newNote(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("note",new Note());
        return "new";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/notes", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(Note note, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("note", note);
        Note.create(note.getContent(), note.getAuthor());
        return "show";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/notes/{noteId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable String noteId) {
        long id = Long.parseLong(noteId);
        Note note = Note.find(id);
        return "show";
    }
}
```

My Note model:

```
package mvc;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

public class Note {

    private Long id;
    private String content;
    private String author;

    public Note() {}

    public Note(Long id, String content, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return content + "by " + author;
    }

    public static void create(String content, String author) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = SpringMvcApplication.getInstance().getJdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO notes(content, author) values (?,?)", content, author);
    }

    public static Note find(Long id) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = SpringMvcApplication.getInstance().getJdbcTemplate();
        List<Note> notes = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT id, content, author FROM notes WHERE id = ?", new Object[]{id},
                new RowMapper<Note>() {
                    @Override
                    public Note mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        return new Note(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("content"),
                                rs.getString("author"));
                    }
                });
        return notes.get(0);
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Spring MVC</name>
<description>MVC Project for Ship It Saturday</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>mvc.SpringMvcApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is with my code here. I was following a few different guides but most of them weren't too clear on what code was doing what. I'm sure there are probably some really obvious issues here, but I'm totally new to Spring and Java so I'm not seeing it.

EDIT:

Here is what I think are the relevant lines of the trace:

```
2015-04-11 19:01:35.125 ERROR 24895 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at mvc.Note.create(Note.java:44)
    at mvc.NoteController.create(NoteController.java:30)
```

I should also mention that the run() method in the SpringMVCApplication class works just fine at creating the table, and if I move the insert and query statements into that method with static data the also work. It's only when I move them into their own methods so that I can use them dynamically that everything falls apart.

Comment: Can you share the beans xml file as well?

Comment: and also please post the exception.  Just a guess right off the bat: are you configuring a `datasource` and a `jdbcTemplate` in your bean config? Normally those would be injected into your `Note` service.

Comment: Where does `SpringMvcApplication.getInstance()` come from? The JdbcTemplate instance in the result seems to be null.

Comment: It's obvious: the JDBC template is null.  You need more than the annotation.  You have to have sufficient XML configuration to instantiate the Spring bean factory and tell it which packages to scan for annotations.  Turn on logging and look at the messages the bean factory is putting out.  It'll tell you what beans have been instantiated.  If you don't see your jdbcTemplate, you have your answer.

Comment: Writing this by hand is a nasty anti-pattern. If you insist on using the Active Record pattern, which has some significant disadvantages (such as making it very difficult to mock persistence), use Spring Roo to handle it for you.

Comment: @Arvind I don't have a beans xml file, and I'm not entirely sure what a Bean is. Like I said, I'm pretty new to Java and I've found it hard to find good resources on the web for learning it compared to other languages. I saw a few guides referencing other xml files that all looked like configuration settings, but none of them gave any indication where those files belong in the app or how to lay them out.

Comment: @Glenn I added the exception to the post.

Comment: @duffymo I figured the problem had something to do with this, but like I said I'm pretty new to Java. I'm not sure how/where to setup those XML configuration files.

Comment: @chrylis I'm not sure what you mean. What are you opposed to writing by hand? The methods for creating and querying? How would you recommend going about it? The reason I went for an ActiveRecord style implementation is because I'm primarily a Rails dev and it's the system I'm used to. I'm not sure what the best practice would be in Java/Spring.

Comment: @ChrisCerami I generally dislike Active Record because (1) using statics makes testing difficult and (2) in Java, getting the collaborators (such as `JdbcTemplate`) reliably can be a challenge. If you really, really want Active Record, Roo will autogenerate them for you, but I recommend the standard Spring Data approach with passive model objects instead of Active Record.

Comment: @chrylis thanks for the input. As a Rails dev I guess I've been falling back on what I know even though Java best practices may be different. I'll have to look into Roo, seems like a useful tool.

Comment: @ChrisCerami FWIW, I personally strongly dislike Roo as a former user. I now use Groovy for domain objects and Spring Data repositories.

Comment: @duffymo You need config for spring, but that doesn't necessarily mean with an xml-file. It can also be through annotated classes.

Comment: @ChrisCerami what is `SpringMvcApplication.getInstance()`? It doesn't appear in your provided code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - my configuration is always a mix of XML and annotations.  I thought you had to have <context:annotation-config/> at a minimum.  Please correct me if that's not so

Comment: @duffymo As far as I know you don't need any XML config; can't find a specific reference in the documentation though (and I only use spring at work, so no code available to check ;).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel legacy for me.  I'll have to see if it's possible to eliminate all of it.  Not sure I want to - mocking and testing seem harder that way.

Comment: @schlauergerd Sorry I must have missed those lines when copying in my code. Because I had to make the create and query methods non-static because jdbcTemplate was non-static for the run method, I needed a way to access the jdbcTemplate instance from outside of the SpringMVCApplication class. To do this I tried using a Singleton of the SpringMVCApplication class so that I could retrieve an instance of it to call create and query on. The thing I'm not sure about with that idea is whether there already is an instance of the SpringMVCApplication class running and I'm creating a second one.

Comment: You're doing everything behind the back of Spring by creating your own instance of SpringMvcApplication using new, and getting that Spring-unaware instance from the static methods in Note. Spring autowires bean instances it creates. Not the one you create yourself. Read the documentation about dependency injection. The static methods in Note should be instance methods of a Spring bean. This Spring bean should have an Autowired JdbcTemplate. And this spring bean should itself be autowired in the controller.

Comment: @ChrisCerami yep, and this will not work. `SpringApplication.run()` returns an `ApplicationContext` which you could save as singleton. With this singleton you could access a JdbcTemplate via `context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class)`

Comment: Thanks @schlauergerd, that makes sense. I was trying to ask a friend how I would go about accessing the already created instance of SpringMVCApplication, but he seemed to disagree that there would be one. I tried implementing your suggestion but I'm getting the error "non-static method run cannot be called from a static context" when I try to do "SpringApplication.run();". What I tried doing was: "public static ApplicationContext instance = SpringApplication.run();" and then "public static JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return instance.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);"

Comment: I'll post a code example as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments your `SpringMvcApplication.getInstance()` will not work as expected. You need something to connect the "spring-world" with the "not-spring-world". A possible solution would be to save the `ApplicationContext` as singleton.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMvcApplication {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
    }

}
```

Maybe you have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'm having an issue when trying to use context.getBean() where it gives me the error: "cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable". Is there another dependency I would need to add to my pom file to be able to use the getBean method?

Comment: The current version of Spring Boot and one of the starter poms (like your pom.xml) should be enough. What kind of exception do you get? What is the root "caused by"?

Comment: Actually, although the IDE underlines it in red like an error, it runs fine. Thanks a lot for the help.